# Postgres json_object. Add json field only if value is not null

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Im using jsob_build_object function to generate json from data in my table.

```
select json_build_object('name', p.name, 'birthday', p.birthday)
FROM Person p limit 2
```

The result is:

```
{"name":"John", "birthday", "2000-01-01"}
{"name":"George", "birthday", "null"}
```

Now as you can see in second row birthday is null. In that case I would like that JSON field (birthday) to not be present there so the result would be:

```
{"name":"John", "birthday", "2000-01-01"}
{"name":"George"}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `json_strip_nulls()`

```
select json_strip_nulls(json_build_object('name', p.name, 'birthday', p.birthday))
FROM person p 
limit 2;
```

Edit 1 (after question has been extended)

If you want to do that conditionally, you can do that with jsonb (because it supports the `||` operator)

```
select jsonb_build_object('name', p.name) || jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('birthday', p.birthday))
from person p;
```

Edit 2 (after Postgres version has been disclosed)

If you are limited to an old version of Postgres you need to use a conditional expression where you only concatenate the JSON object if the column is not null:

```
select jsonb_build_object('name', p.name) 
       || case 
             when birthday is null then '{}'::jsonb 
             else jsonb_build_object('birthday', p.birthday) 
          end
from person p;
```

Comment: But for same cases I would like null to stay, for example for name null is ok, only for birthday if null then field should not be present

Comment: @Witos: then you need to apply that to each key individually. But that is only possible without big troubles when using `jsonb` because the `json` type does not support the `||` operator

Comment: One, more question, would it be possible in postgres 9.4?

Answer (score 0):

While the question is tagged [postgresql-9.4](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.4), there is a new and better solution available since [postgresql-16](/questions/tagged/postgresql-16). It introduces [JSON constructor functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) like `json_object`.

> If `ABSENT ON NULL` is specified, the entire pair is omitted if the *value_expression* is `NULL`.

So you can use

```
SELECT json_object('name': p.name, 'birthday': p.birthday, ABSENT ON NULL)
FROM Person p
LIMIT 2;
```

For JSONB, there is no `jsonb_object` function but rather you use

```
json_object(… ABSENT ON NULL RETURNING jsonb)
```

Comment: I'm not finding that version of `json_object` in [the final PostgreSQL 15 documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html).

Comment: @Mastax Oh no! Looks like [it has been removed](https://www.depesz.com/2022/09/02/sql-json-is-postponed/) in [Postgres 15 beta 4](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-beta-4-released-2507/), apparently due to reviewing (and addressing found issues) taking too long

Comment: @Mastax it became part of Postgres 16