# PostgreSQL JSON building an array without null values

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

The following query

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home'), 
        CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work')
        END)
```

produces

```
[{"use":"Home"},null]
```

When I actually want

```
[{"use":"Home"}]
```

How do I go about doing this? `json_strip_nulls()` does not work for me.

Comment: `json_strip_nulls()` does not remove all nulls by design, it removes all object fields having null as value

Comment: For how to do this in an aggregation, see [Postgresql LEFT JOIN json_agg() ignore/remove NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24155190/1048572). For building an object instead of an array, see [Postgres json_object. Add json field only if value is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48538275/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a PostgreSQL array like that:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_remove(ARRAY[jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home'), 
        CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work') END], null))
```

which does produce:

```
[{"use": "Home"}]
```

while, to be sure:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_remove(ARRAY[jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home'), 
        CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work') END,
        jsonb_build_object('real_use', 'NotHome')], null))
```

does produce:

```
[{"use": "Home"},{"real_use": "NotHome"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a custom function seems to be the simplest way.

```
create or replace function jsonb_build_array_without_nulls(variadic anyarray)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_agg(elem)
    from unnest($1) as elem
    where elem is not null
$$;

select 
    jsonb_build_array_without_nulls(
        jsonb_build_object('use', 'home'), 
        case when 1 = 2 then jsonb_build_object('use', 'work') end
    )

 jsonb_build_array_without_nulls 
---------------------------------
 [{"use": "home"}]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Postgres 16 did introduce [JSON constructor functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) like `json_array`.

> If `ABSENT ON NULL` is specified, `NULL` values are ignored

So you can use

```
SELECT json_array(
    json_object('use': 'Home'), 
    (CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN json_object('use': 'Work') END),
    ABSENT ON NULL
)
```

For JSONB, there is no `jsonb_array` function but rather you use

```
json_array(… ABSENT ON NULL RETURNING jsonb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this query is generaetd dynamically, somehow. If you're in control of the SQL generation, you can also use `ARRAY_AGG(...) FILTER(...)` instead, which, depending on your real world query, might be more convenient than using all the different [array conversion functions suggested by Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432906/521799).

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT json_agg(v) FILTER (WHERE v IS NOT NULL)
  FROM (
    VALUES 
      (jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home')),
      (CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work') END)
  ) t (v)
)
```

Or also:

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT json_agg(v)
  FROM (
    VALUES 
      (jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home')),
      (CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work') END)
  ) t (v)
  WHERE v IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way that this can be handled is the following:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(
  jsonb_build_object('use', 'Home'), 
  CASE 
    WHEN 1 = 2 THEN jsonb_build_object('use', 'Work')
    ELSE '"null"'
  END
) - 'null'
```

(Unfortunately it's not really possible to do much with `null` by itself in postgres -- or most other DBs)

In the case above, `'"null"'` could be replaced with just about any unique string that would not be mistaken for live data in the array. I would not use numbers since `- 0` would actually try to remove the first item from the array, rather than a number within the array. But you could probably use `'"0"'` and remove using something like `- '0'` if you wanted.

For those not using `CASE`, a `COALESCE` could be used to convert nulls into the desired string (alas, no `NVL`, `IFNULL` or `ISNULL` in postgres, but at least `COALESCE` is portable)